# Checking Redis @Configuration in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

Is there a way to check if @Configuration components are being loaded when run a spring boot app ?
I have some 'null pointer' problems when i use this app:

Main class

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pack")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration class

```
package com.pack.config;
@Configuration
public class DataBaseConfig {

    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnFactory() {    
        return new JedisConnectionFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer() {
        StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
        return stringRedisSerializer;
    }

    @Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnFactory());
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

And when i try to use RedisTemplate:

```
public class ServiceDummy  {

    @Autowired
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
    public void save(String data){
        redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("1234", data);
    }

}
```

im getting a nullPointer.

Comment: Is your `ServiceDummy` class marked with `@Component`? Perhaps autowiring isn't picking it up.

Answer (score 0):

As @Todd correctly pointed out, you can't expect Spring to manage beans that are not registered to Spring context.

So you need to:

1. Mark that bean as Spring bean with `@Component` annotation, or in this case `@Service` annotation would be better.
2. Make sure that `ServiceDummy` is under `com.pack` package, so that Spring can scan that component.